# penPHcure package (logistic regression time varying)

Tags: logistic-regression, survival-analysis, cox-regression

In penPHcure package in R logistic regression is designed to be time invariant. How do I make logistic regression time-varying in penPHcure package?

I am trying to run time varying data, so because logistic regression in penPHcure is designed as time-invariant, all variables are removed from the model. I was expecting variables not to be removed.